# Angular ngrx can I execute some code before the init action?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular-router, page-refresh

I'm working with ngrx and I want to rehydrate it after refreshing the page but I also don't want to have my store public in the session storage, I noticed that when refreshing the page the order of events is  **refresh** =>ngrx init => NavigationStart => NavigationEnd, is there any way to execute code between the refresh action and the ngrx init?

Answer (score 0):

The only option is to use session/local storage.
The state store is stored in memory, when the page is reset, the state is also lost.